# Sorting a pandas dataframe on two columns with incremental invariant

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe of imdb episodes that include the show name, season number, episode number and episode rating. I want to sort this dataframe by rating, but with the invariant that a later episode MUST come after an earlier episode for a particular show, even if its rating is higher.

Things I have tried:

- Sorting by rating, season number, episode number (various combinations)
- Creating an absolute episode number based on season number and episode number (e.g. 0, 1, 3 aka S01E01, S01E02, S01E03) and sorting with that

I have managed to come up with a function that does what I want and the code is below. While it works, it's slow, very mutation heavy, and doesn't scale well. I want to find a better way to do this, with or without pandas.

```
def max_rating_by_episode_in_order(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    new_df = pd.DataFrame()
    copy_df = df.copy().sort_values(["showName", "seasonNumber", "episodeNumber"])
    while len(copy_df) > 0:
        next_highest = (
            copy_df.reset_index()
            .groupby("showName")
            .first()
            .sort_values("rating", ascending=False)
            .head(1)
            .reset_index()
        )
        new_df = pd.concat([new_df, next_highest], ignore_index=True)
        copy_df = copy_df.drop(next_highest["index"].values[0])
    return new_df
```

The output should look something like this:

```
showName        seasonNumber  episodeNumber rating
2 Broke Girls   1             1             7.5
'Til Death      1             1             7.4
'Til Death      1             2             7.5
21 Jump Street  1             1             7.4
2 Broke Girls   1             2             7.3
2 Broke Girls   1             3             7.3
2 Broke Girls   1             4             7.3
21 Jump Street  1             2             7.3
21 Jump Street  1             3             7.6
21 Jump Street  1             4             7.5
'Til Death      1             3             7.2
'Til Death      1             4             7.5
'Til Death      1             5             7.6
'Til Death      1             6             7.6
'Til Death      1             7             7.5
'Til Death      1             8             7.6
'Til Death      1             9             7.7
'Til Death      1             10            7.4
'Til Death      1             11            7.4
'Til Death      1             12            7.6
'Til Death      1             13            7.5
'Til Death      1             14            7.6
'Til Death      1             15            7.5
'Til Death      1             16            7.8
2 Broke Girls   1             5             7.2
2 Broke Girls   1             6             7.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the concept of the merge sort and tried to implement a different code as this case is not a simple one, what I am doing is `groupby` showname, then sort each group by `season` , `episode`, and finally compare which group has the highest ranking in the first row, grab the row and deleted and repeat until all groups are empty:

```
df.sort_values(['showName', 'seasonNumber', 'episodeNumber'], inplace=True)

def other_method(df):
    groups = df.groupby(['showName'])
    groups = {k: v for k, v in groups}

    sort_indexes = list()
    keys = [x for x in groups]
    for i in range(df.shape[0]):
        values = np.array([groups[x].iat[0, 3] for x in groups])
        max_value = values.argmax()

        sort_indexes.append(groups[keys[max_value]].index.values[0])
        groups[keys[max_value]] = groups[keys[max_value]].iloc[1:]

        if groups[keys[max_value]].shape[0] == 0:
            del groups[keys[max_value]]
            keys.remove(keys[max_value])

    return df.loc[sort_indexes].copy()
```

I made some comparison to `max_rating_by_episode_in_order` and these are the results:

```
times_1 = []
for i in range(10):
    now = datetime.now()
    df_2 = max_rating_by_episode_in_order(df)
    times_1.append(datetime.now() - now)


times_2 = []
for i in range(10):
    now = datetime.now()
    df_2 = other_method(df)
    times_2.append(datetime.now() - now)

pd.to_timedelta(times_1).mean() # 00:00:00.245583
pd.to_timedelta(times_2).mean() # 00:00:00.022659
```

I am pretty sure there are better ways to implement this complex sorting.

Comment: Thank you so much. Tons of great intuitions here. 
1. You need to take the groupby object and make it a dictionary of dataframe groups that you can then modify (like removing the head).
2. Keep track of just the indicies instead of the entire rows.
3. Removing empty groups explicitly. 
This ultimately led me to a satisfactory solution, using a max heap. The piece we both missed was that we're recomputing the max rating for all groups on every iteration when we only need to keep a sorted list (heap) of the top ratings and simply replace each show on the heap as we pop it off.

Comment: The only major thing that I thought could be improved (besides the heap approach) is  to sort the values first and then do the groupby, since groupbys do stay sorted with pandas. Doing the sort on each individual group was much slower for me in practice.

Comment: Interesting, yeah, testing with small data is really inconclusive. Maybe you can post the solution that worked in case somebody needs it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Much credit to @jcaliz above, I came up with the following function that runs really well even on really large datasets. It still uses an iterating approach, which might be able to be improved upon, but the heap really speeds things up.

```
import pandas as pd
import heapq

def improved_max_rating_by_episode_in_order(in_df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = (
        in_df.copy()
        .reset_index()
        .sort_values(["showName", "seasonNumber", "episodeNumber"])
    )
    # Need to simulate max heap by negating all the ratings to use with a min heap
    df["rating"] = df["rating"] * -1
    gb = df.groupby(["showName"])
    groups = {k: v for k, v in gb}
    sort_indexes = []
    heap = []
    for x in [
        tuple(k.values())
        for k in gb.first()
        .reset_index()[["rating", "showName", "index"]]
        .to_dict("records")
    ]:
        heapq.heappush(heap, x)
    heapq.heapify(heap)
    for _ in range(df.shape[0]):
        rating, showName, index = heapq.heappop(heap)
        sort_indexes.append(index)
        groups[showName] = groups[showName].iloc[1:]
        if groups[showName].shape[0] == 0:
            del groups[showName]
            continue
        heapq.heappush(
            heap,
            tuple(
                groups[showName]
                .head(1)[["rating", "showName", "index"]]
                .to_dict("records")[0]
                .values()
            ),
        )
    return in_df.loc[sort_indexes]
```